# What i can use instead of (ios :: in )in C++ to give the same result in my code?

Tags: c++

What can I use instead of `(ios::in)` in C++ to give the same result?

I want something that gives the same result as this line:

```cpp
ifstream in("input.txt", ios::in);
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need something "instead"? Why not continue using your working solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can omit `ios__in` since a `std::ifstream` already has its mode set to `ios_base::in` by default. `ios::in` is just an alias for `ios_base::in`.

```cpp
ifstream in("input.txt");
```

You can see the constructor for `std::ifstream` here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

```cpp
 explicit basic_ifstream( const char* filename,  
                std::ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

Where the `mode` is set to `ios_base::in` by default.